# Getting image from Django on AWS, to Android Glide. 404 error

Tags: android, django, amazon-web-services

I implemented REST API using Django-rest-framework, deployed with AWS-ec2.

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'images')
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='author.username')
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('author', 'text', 'image')
    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['author'] = self.context['request'].user
        return super(PostSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

**urls.py**

```
router = SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'posts', views.PostViewSet, base_name='posts')
urlpatterns = router.urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    ]
```

**views.py**

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
```

So, it returned:

```
  {
    "author": "ghdalsrn",
    "text": "11",
    "image": "http://ec2-52-78-138-143.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/images/images/Avril_Lavigne_-_00_-_Sk8er_Girl_-_Frontcover_-simplemp3s.jpg"
  }
```

I used  `"image": "http://ec2-52-78-138-143.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/images/images/Avril_Lavigne_-_00_-_Sk8er_Girl_-_Frontcover_-simplemp3s.jpg"` on my Android studio.

**Android MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ImageView mimage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_image);

        Glide.with(this)
                .load("http://ec2-52-78-138-143.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/images/images/Avril_Lavigne_-_00_-_Sk8er_Girl_-_Frontcover_-simplemp3s.jpg")
                .centerCrop()
                .into(mimage);
```

But, according to my putty message,

**putty**

`"GET /images/images/filename_sk8er_Girl.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 5184`

Also my Android application doesn't show any image.

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Does your picture load in your browser ?

Comment: @navit No, it doesn't too. It returned `Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://ec2-52-78-138-143.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/images/images/Avril_Lavigne_-_00_-_Sk8er_Girl_-_Frontcover_-simplemp3s.jpg`

Comment: Your image is not accessible. Check your file location on the file system and try to figure out the URL.

Comment: @navit , I'm very sorry for saying this, Could you give me more hint? Because I'm very newbie, so i can't know where i should to start checking file system

Comment: Browse your directory structure under images. Where is the image located ?

Comment: @navit My image files are in `New/images/images`. manage.py is in `New`. I want it is enough answer for your ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your folder structure in your server is wrong. According to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/) you should put your static files under a structure like this:

```
[home folder where manage.py is located]/[module_name]/[images, defined in settings.py]/[module_name]/[image_file_name]
```

In your case:

```
New/MyModule/images/MyModule/Avril_Lavigne_-_00_‌​-_Sk8er_Girl_-_Front‌​cover_-simplemp3s.jp‌​g
```

Double check your folder structures. You may have to update your file paths in your database.

Comment: From your nice answer, I gave a lot of help. Thank you